# How do you unlock the Chicago Typewriter in Resident Evil 4?

Tags: resident-evil-4-2005

What needs to be accomplished or how do you unlock the Chicago Typewriter, the tommy gun in Resident Evil 4 for Xbox One? I just finished the main story with Leon and started the "Separate Ways" extra story line with Eda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the GameCube version, it is available for 1,000,000₧ after beating the Assignment Ada minigame. In all other versions, beating Separate Ways will unlock this gun for the main game for the same price, while beating Assignment Ada will unlock it for Separate Ways, where it costs 300,000₧.

Source http://residentevil.wikia.com/wiki/Chicago_Typewriter

Comment: No worries. It may well be the most fun gun in any game as well. enjoy!

Comment: I know right! Do you know how to get the Laser Gun by chance? Called the P somethin somethin

Comment: You have to complete the game on professional mode. which will be easy once you have the Chicago Typewriter

Comment: true true I love this game